# ImageJ: how to get Image inside GenericDialog to repaint?

Tags: plugins, awt, imagej

In my ImageJ plugin I display a GenericDialog which has a bunch of images attached to it, like this:

```
// global:
ColorProcessor cp = new ColorProcessor(50, 50); // new ColorProcessor
ImagePlus ip;

public void run(ImageProcessor ip) {
  GenericDialog gdiag = new GenericDialog("Foo"); // new Dialolg

  gdiag.addDialogListener(this); // adding Listener
  gdiag.addMessage("Lorem Ipsum"); // adding Message
  gdiag.addSlider("Bar", 1, 360, 1); // adding Slider

  Color c = new Color(r, g, b);
  cp.setColor(tarColor);
  cp.fill();
  ip = new ImagePlus("fooimg", cp);

  gdiag.addImage(ip);
  gdiag.showDialog();
}
```

I keep a reference to the Colorprocessor and the ImagePlus. When the slider gets moved on the GenericDialog, my the dialogItemChanged() event fires. Here I change the Color on the Image:

```
public boolean dialogItemChanged(GenericDialog gd, AWTEvent event) {
  float fooVal = (float) ((Scrollbar)(gd.getSliders().get(0))).getValue();

  // calculating color based on fooVal ...

  Color selColor = new Color(r, g, b);
  cp.setColor(selColor);
  cp.fill();
}
```

Now when I run this, the Color in the Image does not update. Only when I change the size of the dialog and move the border over the image, the color displays correctly.

How can I force the dialog to repaint?

I tried so many different updates & repaints, I am out of options.

Comment: Did you try `ip.updateAndDraw()`? Did you try `gd.validate(); gd.repaint();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wayne Rasband added this capability in the 1.51b12 daily build of ImageJ; see [his response on the ImageJ mailing list](http://imagej.1557.x6.nabble.com/Repaint-Image-inside-GenericDialog-tt5016483.html#a5016487), where this question was cross-posted.